# Dyadic reciprocity for binary outcome in asymmetric block design

Tags: logistic, glmmtmb

I am trying to estimate dyadic reciprocity in a binary outcome collected with asymmetric block design (speed-dating where each person indicates whether or not they are interested in a second date with each partner). I am aware that dyadic reciprocity in the social relations model can be estimated by the ratio of the dyad variance to the sum of the dyad variance plus the residual variance, which for binary outcome is $ {\pi^2/3} $. I estimated it with the *glmmTMB* package in R. Yet, when I add a random variable representing the dyads to the model, it estimates its variance near zero, showing that the model's deviance with and without the dyad variances are the same, and the p-value for their difference is 1. This is strange because of the unlikely p-value of 1 and conceptually suggesting that people offer dates with a probability of being reciprocated at a chance level.

I took two alternative approaches, which may not be appropriate, to estimate the dyadic reciprocity. First, I estimated it with a model of the asymmetric block design, assuming that the binary outcome was continuous. That model suggested a dyadic reciprocity correlation of .07 with p = .034. Given that the success rate in this sample is about 45% (chance of offering a second date), I am surprised that the Gaussian model is so different from the binary model. Next, I correlated the residuals of the binary model and obtained a correlation of .08 with p = .012.

I supply a minimal code to replicate the above results. My question is, which estimate is correct, or have I failed to specify correctly the dyadic variance for binary outcome?

```
require("glmmTMB")

# In the first run of this code, read the data from OSF and store it in the 
# local directory. In each later run, read it from the local directory.
if(file.exists("Dating.csv")) {
  x <- read.csv("Dating.csv")
} else {
  x <- read.csv("https://osf.io/download/yqcbb/")
  write.csv(x, "Dating.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}

# Rename variables and prepare contrast code, dummy codes, and ID variables
x$groupID <- as.factor(x$selfid %/% 100) 
x         <- x[, c("groupID", "selfid", "otherid", "sex", "date.again")]
names(x)  <- c("groupID", "actorID", "partnerID", "gender", "date.again")

x$MWvWM   <- ifelse(x$gender == 1, .5, -.5)   #contrast code
x$MW      <- ifelse(x$gender == 1, 1, 0)      #dummy code for men    
x$WM      <- ifelse(x$gender == 0, 1, 0)      #dummy code for women
x$MID     <- ifelse(x$gender == 1, x$actorID, x$partnerID) # a unique id for each man 
x$WID     <- ifelse(x$gender == 0, x$actorID, x$partnerID) # a unique id for each woman
x$dyadID  <- paste(x$MID, x$WID, sep = "-")

# Model binary outcome for asymmetric block design
fit1 <-
  glmmTMB(
    date.again ~ 1 + MWvWM
    + (1 | dyadID)
    + (0 + MW + WM | groupID:MID)
    + (0 + WM + MW | groupID:WID),
    data = x,
    family = binomial(link = "logit")
  )
# Compute dyadic reciprocity
unlist(VarCorr(fit1))[1]/(unlist(VarCorr(fit1))[1] + (pi^2)/3)

# Test the significance of dyadic reciprocity
fit2 <- update(fit1, . ~ . - (1 | dyadID), data = x)
anova(fit1, fit2)

# Pretend the outcome is continuous
fit3 <- glmmTMB(date.again ~ 1 + MWvWM
                 + us(0 + MW + WM | groupID:MID) 
                 + us(0 + WM + MW | groupID:WID)
                 + us(0 + MW + WM | groupID:MID:WID),
                 data = x,
                 family = gaussian(link = "identity"), 
                 dispformula = ~0
                )
# Dyadic reciprocity is estimated as .07
summary(fit3)

# Test the significance of the dyadic reciprocity
fit4 <- update(fit3, . ~ . - us(0 + MW + WM | groupID:MID:WID)
                           + us(0 + WM | groupID:MID:WID)
                           + us(0 + MW | groupID:MID:WID)
                           , data = x)
# Dyadic reciprocity is significant, p = .034.
anova(fit3, fit4)

##Prepare data to calculate dyadic reciprocity with residuals
dating.res  <- as.data.frame(residuals(fit2))
x           <- cbind(x, dating.res)
x$pairID    <- ifelse(x$gender == 1, 
                      paste0(x$actorID,   "-", x$partnerID),
                      paste0(x$partnerID, "-", x$actorID))
x$residuals <- as.numeric(residuals(fit4))
men         <- x[which(x$gender == 1), c("pairID", "residuals")]
women       <- x[which(x$gender == 0), c("pairID", "residuals")]
Dyadic      <- na.omit(merge(men, women, by = "pairID"))

# Dyadic reciprocity is .08 and p = .012
cor.test(Dyadic[, "residuals.x"], Dyadic[, "residuals.y"])
```